# Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined youtube api

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube, youtube-api

Cannot get user channel using youtube api, don't know what is going wrong. Here's my code:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    gapi.load('client', this.initGoogleAuthentication.bind(this));
}

initGoogleAuthentication() {
    this.socialService.getConfiguration().subscribe(this.onConfigurationLoaded.bind(this));
}

onConfigurationLoaded(operation: OperationDataResult<Config>) {
    if (operation && operation.success) {

        const config = operation.model;

        gapi.client.setApiKey(config.youtubeSecret);
        gapi.auth.init(this.checkAuth());

    } else {
        console.log('failed loaded configuration ', operation);
    }
}

checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: this.oAuthKey,
            scope: this.scopeLink, // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
            immediate: true
        },
        this.handlaOAuthReslult.bind(this));
}

handlaOAuthReslult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {

        gapi.client.load('youtube',
            'v3',
            () => {
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                    mine: true,
                    part: 'id'
                });
                request.execute(response => {
                    let playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                });
            });
    } else {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: this.oAuthKey,
                scope: this.scopeLink,
                immediate: false
            }, this.handlaOAuthReslult.bind(this));
    }
}
```

It falls in handlaOAuthReslult function where it have two error where executing `gapi.client.load` with error:

```
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest?fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods%2CbatchPath%2Cid&pp=0&key=mykey
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400
```

and 2nd error on executing `gapi.client.youtube.channels.list` where it tells that `channels`is undefined

Comment: Check the [JavaScript Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) for your Javascript code reference. Make sure the javascript library is loaded then follow the flow on how to call the Youtube API methods. This is error is similar in a way with this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713090/youtube-data-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-search-of-undefine) wherein the methods were being called while the libraries were not yet loaded.

Comment: @noogui, already find out that on my page view, in child's component i've two actions with gapi - google then youtube. if i'm commenting load for google, youtube works fine if not - error with undefined. Is there way to somehow dispose gapi after google plus is loaded?

Comment: also, javascript library i'm loading from my main layout `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>`